editing ip in openvpn config file with expressvpn
I was recently trying to set up a new tunnel for express vpn in openvpn, but i needed to change the allowed ip to:185.34.0.0/16 in the config file. The problem is, with the config file that expressvpn gave me, i dont know where the ip is and dont know how to change it (forgive me if i am using the wrong terms, i am new to this subject). under this text i am going to paste a spare config that i am not using thats still from express vpn, could someone please point out how to change the server ip or the allowed ip?
I would really appreciate any help and would thank anybody for teaching me something new in this subject
ps: i am on windows 10
dev tun
fast-io
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
remote italy-cosenza-ca-version-2.expressnetw.com 1195
remote-random
pull
comp-lzo no
tls-client
verify-x509-name Server name-prefix
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
route-method exe
route-delay 2
tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix 1200
verb 3
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
auth-user-pass

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
48d9999bd71095b10649c7cb471c1051
b1afdece597cea06909b99303a18c674
01597b12c04a787e98cdb619ee960d90
a0165529dc650f3a5c6fbe77c91c137d
cf55d863fcbe314df5f0b45dbe974d9b
de33ef5b4803c3985531c6c23ca6906d
6cd028efc8585d1b9e71003566bd7891
b9cc9212bcba510109922eed87f5c8e6
6d8e59cbd82575261f02777372b2cd4c
a5214c4a6513ff26dd568f574fd40d6c
d450fc788160ff68434ce2bf6afb00e7
10a3198538f14c4d45d84ab42637872e
778a6b35a124e700920879f1d003ba93
dccdb953cdf32bea03f365760b0ed800
2098d4ce20d045b45a83a8432cc73767
7aed27125592a7148d25c87fdbe0a3f6
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----


-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


What do you mean by allowed ip? Which server you would be connecting to is determined by remote.
